# Как сделать копию словаря и всех его элементов?

Tags: c#

Пробовал делать копию вот так:

```
    Class1 newClass1 = new Class1("first");
    Dictionary<int, Class1> d1 = new Dictionary<int, Class1> { { 1, newClass1 } };
    Dictionary<int, Class1> d2 = new Dictionary<int, Class1>(d1);
    d2[1].x = "second";
    Console.WriteLine(d1[1].x);
```

Где Class1:

```
class Class1
{
    public string x;

    public Class1(string x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

В консоль выводиться `second`. Я хочу иметь копию, при изменении элементов который не менялись бы элементы исходного словаря.

Важно, что бы копия создавалась достаточно быстро: в словаре могут быть девятки тысяч элементов и нужно будет создавать до сотен копий, меньше чем за секунду.

Comment: [Например так](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.22.php), научитесь отличать [ссылочные и значимые типы](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.16.php).

Comment: aepot Я понимаю разницу и понимаю в чём проблема. Просто хотел узнать какие варианты решения существуют... Но как я понял, все варианты достаточно затратны и лучше будет переделать логику

Comment: Если вам нужны сотни копий в секунду, вероятно, у вас многопоточка. Для таких сценариев стоит рассмотреть иммутабельные (неизменяемые) коллекции. [ImmutableDictionary](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary-2?view=net-5.0). PS: элементы в словаре тоже должны быть иммутабельными.

Comment: У вас 2 варианта, либо копирование через явную реализацию, либо через сериализацию, то есть рефлексию. Явная реализация быстрее.